# Apply id to list item link using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to add an id to a unordered list item. Not to the `<li>` tag, but inside the `<li>` tag, like so:

`<li><a href="#" id="Here i want to add an id"></a></li>`

So if you can see, inside the a tag, I want to add an ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('li > a').attr('id', 'id_to_add');
```

Ideally you'll have a more specific selector for that `li`. You should give your `li` a `class` or `id` that you can use to better-identify it, e.g.

```
<li class="needs-id">...

$('li.needs-id > a').attr('id', '...');
```

Comment: I wish there's only one `li > a`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make sure you don't introduce duplicate id's into your document. As such you will need to test if an id is already used in the document. Using `attr('id', 'some_id')` on a set of nodes, will directly introduce duplicates. As such, you will have to do some iterations using `.each`. Also you need to make sure that you don't accidentally remove existing id's, which could cause unwanted side effects.

```
function generateId(base) {
    generateId.iterator = generateId.iterator || 1;
    base = base || '';
    while (document.getElementById(base + generateId.iterator)) {
       generateId.iterator ++;
    }
    return base + generateId.iterator;
}

$('li > a').each(function() {
    this.id = this.id || generateId();
});
```